# Bootstrap 5: add tabs to slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I created slider using Bootstrap 5. Currently result is:

```html
     <head>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="col-xl-6 col-md-12 ratio_65">
        <div class="row g-3">
          <div class="col-xl-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="home-contain">
              <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-indicators">
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-merry-christmas-new-year-card-with-realistic-blue-decoration_1361-3053.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1673707221~exp=1673707821~hmac=221ab41285bb5fac3c32463b2bbf57775f7a7f3fa66525b2bd94233df897dd67" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-merry-christmas-new-year-card-with-realistic-blue-decoration_1361-3053.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1673707221~exp=1673707821~hmac=221ab41285bb5fac3c32463b2bbf57775f7a7f3fa66525b2bd94233df897dd67" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-merry-christmas-new-year-card-with-realistic-blue-decoration_1361-3053.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1673707221~exp=1673707821~hmac=221ab41285bb5fac3c32463b2bbf57775f7a7f3fa66525b2bd94233df897dd67" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="home-detail text-white p-center text-center">
                <div>
                  <h4 class="text-center">
                    <!--Organic Lifestyle-->
                  </h4>
                  <h5 class="text-center">
                    <!--Best Weekend Sales-->
                  </h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I read the Bootstrap documentation about carousel, also tried all available "example" in the search engine. Unfortunately, there is no way I can achieve such an effect.

I try get effect and add name every slider as tab. Can anyone little help me on how to add extra tabs like this? I paste example photo here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, Bootstrap does not support carousel slider tabs out of the box. But because Bootstrap uses the data attributes `data-bs-target` and `data-bs-slide-to` for the indicators you can apply them to other elements.

For example, apply them on a list outside of the carousel, which are the slider tabs:

```
<ul class="custom-indicators">
  <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" aria-label="Slide 1">
    Slide 1
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

The slider tabs in the snippet has more classes to position everything using a `row` with four columns `col`. Simply clicking on a `<li>` element will already set the carousel to that slide index (0).

To style the active slider tab use JavaScript by toggling a class on it, like `.active` and style it using CSS.

Here are two basic examples, using Jquery or plain Javascript.

##### Solution with Jquery

Lucky for us, [Bootstrap’s carousel class exposes events for hooking into carousel functionality](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/carousel/#events), like `slide.bs.carousel`:

```
$('#carouselExampleIndicators').on('slide.bs.carousel', event => { ... });
```

This function will fire whenever the carousel transitions to another slide. Inside access the event property `to`, which holds the index of the next slide. Then toggle the `active` class:

```
const nextSlide = event.to;
$('.custom-indicators li').removeClass('active');
$('.custom-indicators li[data-bs-slide-to=' + nextSlide + ']').addClass('active');
```

Now apply some custom CSS to style the tabs, and that's. Here's the complete basic example of custom indicators that can be styled:

```js
$('#carouselExampleIndicators').on('slide.bs.carousel', event => {
  const nextSlide = event.to;
  $('.custom-indicators li').removeClass('active');
  $('.custom-indicators li[data-bs-slide-to=' + nextSlide + ']').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.custom-indicators li {
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
}

.custom-indicators li.active {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="col-xl-6 col-md-12 ratio_65">
  <div class="row g-3">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="home-contain">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" >
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-merry-christmas-new-year-card-with-realistic-blue-decoration_1361-3053.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1673707221~exp=1673707821~hmac=221ab41285bb5fac3c32463b2bbf57775f7a7f3fa66525b2bd94233df897dd67" class="d-block w-100"
                alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-merry-christmas-new-year-card-with-realistic-blue-decoration_1361-3053.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1673707221~exp=1673707821~hmac=221ab41285bb5fac3c32463b2bbf57775f7a7f3fa66525b2bd94233df897dd67" class="d-block w-100"
                alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-merry-christmas-new-year-card-with-realistic-blue-decoration_1361-3053.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1673707221~exp=1673707821~hmac=221ab41285bb5fac3c32463b2bbf57775f7a7f3fa66525b2bd94233df897dd67" class="d-block w-100"
                alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-merry-christmas-new-year-card-with-realistic-blue-decoration_1361-3053.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1673707221~exp=1673707821~hmac=221ab41285bb5fac3c32463b2bbf57775f7a7f3fa66525b2bd94233df897dd67" class="d-block w-100"
                alt="...">
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="">
          <ul class="list-unstyled row gx-0 text-center text-secondary custom-indicators" role="button">
            <li class="col p-2 active" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" aria-label="Slide 1">
              Slide 1
            </li>
            <li class="col p-2" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2">
              Slide 2
            </li>
            <li class="col p-2" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3">
              Slide 3
            </li>
            <li class="col p-2" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4">
              Slide 4
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

##### Solution with JavaScript


Here's a solution that uses plain Javascript to accomplish the same thing. It loops over all slider tabs removing the class `active` and applies it on the slider tab that has the index (`data-bs-slide-to="?"`) of the next slide.

```js
var carousel = document.querySelector('#carouselExampleIndicators');

carousel.addEventListener('slide.bs.carousel', event => {
  var nextSlide = event.to;
  var customIndicators = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-indicators li');
  for (var i = 0; i < customIndicators.length; i++) {
    customIndicators[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  document.querySelector('.custom-indicators li[data-bs-slide-to="' + nextSlide + '"]').classList.add('active');
});
```

```css
.custom-indicators li {
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
}

.custom-indicators li.active {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="col-xl-6 col-md-12 ratio_65">
  <div class="row g-3">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="home-contain">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-merry-christmas-new-year-card-with-realistic-blue-decoration_1361-3053.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1673707221~exp=1673707821~hmac=221ab41285bb5fac3c32463b2bbf57775f7a7f3fa66525b2bd94233df897dd67" class="d-block w-100"
                alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-merry-christmas-new-year-card-with-realistic-blue-decoration_1361-3053.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1673707221~exp=1673707821~hmac=221ab41285bb5fac3c32463b2bbf57775f7a7f3fa66525b2bd94233df897dd67" class="d-block w-100"
                alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-merry-christmas-new-year-card-with-realistic-blue-decoration_1361-3053.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1673707221~exp=1673707821~hmac=221ab41285bb5fac3c32463b2bbf57775f7a7f3fa66525b2bd94233df897dd67" class="d-block w-100"
                alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-merry-christmas-new-year-card-with-realistic-blue-decoration_1361-3053.jpg?w=1380&t=st=1673707221~exp=1673707821~hmac=221ab41285bb5fac3c32463b2bbf57775f7a7f3fa66525b2bd94233df897dd67" class="d-block w-100"
                alt="...">
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="">
          <ul class="list-unstyled row gx-0 text-center text-secondary custom-indicators" role="button">
            <li class="col p-2 active" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" aria-label="Slide 1">
              Slide 1
            </li>
            <li class="col p-2" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2">
              Slide 2
            </li>
            <li class="col p-2" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3">
              Slide 3
            </li>
            <li class="col p-2" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4">
              Slide 4
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help!  It's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for explain everything.